# how to tell TestNg to execute a test as the final test in a group?

Tags: java, testng, integration-testing

Is there a way that I can tell testNG to execute a particular test which belongs to a group to be executed as the final test in that group?

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try to achieve this with setting the test `priority` value via it's `@Test` annotation. Due to [java docs](http://testng.org/javadoc/org/testng/annotations/Test.html#priority()), the default priority value is 0, that means, if you manually set some test priority to greater value, this test will run after all the tests with the default priority value.

Comment: That makes sense. Will try it out

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [@AfterGroups](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotations)?

> @AfterGroups: The list of groups that this configuration method will
>   run after. This method is guaranteed to run shortly after the last
>   test method that belongs to any of these groups is invoked.